# I want to list the data for a CEP API

Tags: php, laravel

I want to list this data:

```json
[
    {
        "cep": "91790-072",
        "logradouro": "Rua Domingos José Poli",
        "complemento": "",
        "bairro": "Restinga",
        "localidade": "Porto Alegre",
        "uf": "RS",
        "ibge": "4314902",
        "gia": "",
        "ddd": "51",
        "siafi": "8801"
    },
    {
        "cep": "91910-420",
        "logradouro": "Rua José Domingos Varella",
        "complemento": "",
        "bairro": "Cavalhada",
        "localidade": "Porto Alegre",
        "uf": "RS",
        "ibge": "4314902",
        "gia": "",
        "ddd": "51",
        "siafi": "8801"
    },
    {
        "cep": "90420-200",
        "logradouro": "Rua Domingos José de Almeida",
        "complemento": "",
        "bairro": "Rio Branco",
        "localidade": "Porto Alegre",
        "uf": "RS",
        "ibge": "4314902",
        "gia": "",
        "ddd": "51",
        "siafi": "8801"
    }
]
```

I'm using this code to get the data

```php
$url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/RS/Porto%20Alegre/Domingos+Jose/json/";
$get = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

I see this results:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#1358 ▶}
  1 => {#1361 ▶}
  2 => {#1366 ▶}
]
```

Then I try to use the foreach, but this is getting only 1 result:

```php
foreach ($get as $chave => $valor) {
    dd($valor);
}
```

```
{#1357 ▼
  +"cep": "91790-072"
  +"logradouro": "Rua Domingos José Poli"
  +"complemento": ""
  +"bairro": "Restinga"
  +"localidade": "Porto Alegre"
  +"uf": "RS"
  +"ibge": "4314902"
  +"gia": ""
  +"ddd": "51"
  +"siafi": "8801"
}
```

I want to make a search bar with the results dynamically, but I can't list the data of this API, why?

Comment: English only on Stackoverflow please :)

Comment: Because `dd($valor);` is for **dump and die**. If you make a `dd`, then your process will **dump** then **die()** after the first loop

Comment: Change your `dd` to `dump`